# Simple arithmetic in an exam

Tags: calculations, exam

How can I do some simple calculations in LaTeX?

Specifically, I want to divide `\numpoints` (part of the `exam` package) by 1.10. That is, I want to do something like this:

`Grade: \underline{\hspace{2cm}} out of \numpoints<DIVIDED BY 1.1> (points available \numpoints).`

Comment: Packages `\calc`, `calculator` and the `pgfmath` utilities might help.

Comment: In addition, you should be more specific about the particular needs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) it's really simple:

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calcnumpoints}{\@ifundefined{exam@numpoints}{0}{\exam@numpoints}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \titledquestion{First Question}[5]
  \titledquestion{Second Question}[5]
  \titledquestion{Third Question}[2]
  \titledquestion{Fourth Question}[2]
\end{questions}

\numpoints

\calc{round(\calcnumpoints/1.1,1)}

\end{document}
```

`\calc` performs any floating point calculation, which in the above case is rounded to one decimal. Since `\numpoints` outputs somewhat like a reference (**??** if it doesn't exist and `\exam@numpoints` otherwise), I've made an alternative definition `\calcnumpoints` which defaults to 0 if `\exam@numpoints` is not yet defined. This way you can use it in calculations as expected.

Comment: Is there a "round down", or "floor" function? I ended up with this statement: `\calc{round(0.9*\numpoints,0)-1})`. I'd prefer a floor statement, but cannot find much documentation on `expl3` (see: http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3). I tried using `floor`.

Comment: @Jeff: This is probably because `\exam@numpoints` was undefined. I've updated my answer to use a different `\calcnumpoints` that you can use in calculations. Now, if you want to see the floor, use `floor(...,n)`. The argument `n` of `floor` implies a round down (towards negative infinity) to the nearest 10^`n`.